# Can you nest JavaScript in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

I found this ad rotator script and I want to nest JavaScript inside like this below. I get errors thrown how would I accomplish this.

```
<?php 
// random number 1 - 100 $result_random = rand(1, 100); 

// if result less than or equal 70, display ad1 (70%) 
if($result_random <= 70){ 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myads.com'></script>"; 
} 
// if result less than or equal 90, display ad2 (20%) 
else if($result_random <= 90){ 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myads.com'></script>";
} 
// if result less than or equal 100, display ad3 (10%)
else { 
 echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myads.com'></script>"; 
}
```

Comment: Could the error have to do with the fact that `$result_random` doesn't exist because it's commented out?

Comment: I get errors in building because of the ticks ''''

Comment: What is the exact error message? The posted code, after you move `$result_random = rand(1, 100);` to a new line, works just fine.

Comment: This is my error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP to output the script source to the user's browser, but you can't just include and run Javascript inside of a PHP application.

Your output of:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myads.com'></script>
```

Is the correct behavior. The client would then try to include that script source.

If you're going to do conditional includes, you'll want to echo those out between the head tags of your page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <?php
      // process, echo out a <script />
    ?>
  </head>
  <body>...</body>
</html>
```

Comment: basically anywhere you can write HTML, you can write out javascript or jQuery instead.

Comment: @CsharpBeginner: I just ran the code, and the output was `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myads.com'></script>`. I'm not sure what is failing for you, unless you're not showing the full script source.

Comment: Im getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 1):

**Problem/Cause:**

Because this line

```
// random number 1 - 100 $result_random = rand(1, 100);
```

is commented out,

this line

```
if($result_random <= 70){
```

and this line

```
else if($result_random <= 90){
```

gonna cause an error something in the lines of `Undefined Variable $result_random in line X`

[Your Code @ Codepad.org/saPRtKPU](http://codepad.org/saPRtKPU)

*(UPDATE: Ok, you are not getting any error, but because `$result_random` is undefined, only the last `else`(ads3) case is getting executed **everytime**. Any Undefined variable holds the `NULL` value http://codepad.org/vVHMrWkl)*

**Solution:**

Change this line

```
// random number 1 - 100 $result_random = rand(1, 100);
```

to

```
// random number 1 - 100
$result_random = rand(1, 100);
```

I.e. insert a line-break / carriage return (<kbd>Enter</kbd> in Windows) before `$result_random....`

It should solve the problem, but if now, please post the exact error message you are getting.

BTW, Your all three SRCs for scripts are same i.e. `http://myads.com/`. I guess that it is just an example, but even then, while testing, we can't know if we are getting true random results. So I have appended `ad1`, `ad2`, `ad3` to the respective URLs.

**Full Code:**

```
<?php 
// random number 1 - 100
$result_random = rand(1, 100); 

// if result less than or equal 70, display ad1 (70%) 
if($result_random <= 70){ 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myads.com/ad1'></script>"; 
} // if result less than or equal 90, display ad2 (20%) 
    else if($result_random <= 90){ 
      echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myads.com/ad2'></script>";
    }// if result less than or equal 100, display ad3 (10%)
        else { 
             echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myads.com/ad3'></script>"; 
        } 

//Just for testing
echo "\r\nRandom Number is: ".$result_random;
```

[Live Demo @ Codepad.org http://codepad.org/oymuBk8w](http://codepad.org/oymuBk8w)

Answer (score -1):

You need to put this code in  section of your File. Only then it will work

it will not wqrk inside Php.

Js file will work only when you include them in html or using dynamic code(php) n html

Comment: Downvoted. This is Wrong. The way OP is coding, JS should work, provided `src` attribute is valid.